# Alterar margem de um CheckBox dinamicamente

Tags: java, android

Este atributo pode ser alterado dinâmicamente no código java?

```
android:layout_marginTop
```

Tenho um `CheckBox` gerado dinamicamente, e preciso que ele fique com uma margem.

<sub>Código java:</sub>

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
//cb.setId();
//cb.setText();
cb.setChecked();
_relativeLayout.addView(cb);
```

Sem a margem, ele é exibido deste jeito:

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Um em cima do outro.

**EDIÇÃO:**

Com a margem, ele não é exibido.

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams ml = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(10, 10);
ml.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
//cb.setId();
//cb.setText();
cb.setChecked(true);
cb.setLayoutParams(ml);
_relativeLayout.addView(cb);
```

**EDIÇÃO 2**

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ml = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ml.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {   
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    //ml.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, _relativeLayoutCbIngredientes);
    cb.setLayoutParams(ml);
    _relativeLayoutCbIngredientes.addView(cb);
}
```

Mesmo setando a `margem` continua um cima do outro, o problema não é a `margem`, e acho que sim o `Bellow`.

Como adicionar o `Bellow` no `CheckBox` sendo que ele é gerado dinamicamente?

Comment: Exception, crie um `MarginLayoutParams` e coloque `topMargin` nele. O `LayoutParams` vai depender de qual é o tipo do pai do `CheckBox`.

Comment: o que você quis dizer com `tipo`? Se é `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`...?

Comment: A classe `ViewGroup` tem uma classe `LayoutParams` apenas com `width` e `height`. Cada subclasse (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` e etc) define uma classe `LayoutParams` que herda de `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` e algumas de `MarginLayoutParams`. Essa última aceita margens, e também caracteriza um `ViewGroup` que trata margens. O tipo seria qual subclasse é o pai do `CheckBox`.

Comment: @Wakim, não sei se entendi direito, adicionei o `MarginLayoutParams` e agora não é exibido os `CheckBoxes`. Atualizei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Como a `View` que deve ficar acima do `CheckBox` é gerado dinâmicamente, essa solução usando `RelativeLayout.BELOW` não atende e gera problemas mesmo adicionando um `id` auto-gerado. A cada `addView` o `RelativeLayout` vai precisar reavaliar todas as regras, gerando um "overhead" na solução.

Uma solução simples seria adotar um `LinearLayout` com `orientation="vertical"`, porque a cada item inserido o `LinearLayout` o coloca abaixo do anterior.

A única modificação ao código atual seria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

    // Precisa gerar um LayoutParams para cada View, não recomendo reutilizar.
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ml = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // Margem opcional
    ml.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    cb.setLayoutParams(ml);

    _linearLayoutCbIngredientes.addView(cb);
}
```

---

Para adicionar margem dinâmicamente em uma `View` que está adicionando ao Layout, precisa:

1. Criar o `LayoutParams` específico da subclasse da `ViewGroup` que irá adicionar a `View`. O Construtor do `LayoutParams` recebe o `layout_width` e `layout_height` que a `View` terá.
2. Setar os valores antes de chamar o `addView(View view)` ou usar o `addView(View view, LayoutParams param)`.

Um exemplo:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ml = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// A classe RelativeLayout.LayoutParams extende MarginLayoutParams,
// verificado na documentacao: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

ml.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);

CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);

cb.setChecked(true);

// Ou
cb.setLayoutParams(ml);
_relativeLayout.addView(cb);

// Ou
_relativeLayout.addView(cb, ml);
```

Como sugestão, porque não usa uma regra para posicionar uma `View` abaixo de outra?

Usando a regra ficaria:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ml = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// A classe RelativeLayout.LayoutParams extende MarginLayoutParams,
// verificado na documentacao: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

// Adiciona uma regra para o CheckBox ficar abaixo da View existente cujo id seja viewAcima.
// Parto do pressuposto que essa View ja esta no layout como mostrado na imagem.

ml.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.viewAcima);

CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);

cb.setChecked(true);

// Ou
cb.setLayoutParams(ml);
_relativeLayout.addView(cb);

// Ou
_relativeLayout.addView(cb, ml);
```

Nesse segundo caso, o `RelativeLayout` irá adicionar mais uma restrição em que a sua `CheckBox` deve ficar abaixo da `viewAcima`.

Acredito que essa forma seja mais correta, porque usar uma margem fixa pode gerar problema dependendo da densidade e do tamanho de tela e etc do dispositivo. Sendo assim, pode ser que em alguns dispositivos a margem fixa que deu não é suficiente para colocar o `CheckBox` abaixo da outra `View`.

Comment: Acho que o problema que estou tendo é com o `Bellow` mesmo. Como estou gerando o `CheckBox` dinâmicamente, está adicionando um em cima do outro. Mas, para eu adicionar o `Bellow`, precisaria pegar o `CheckBox`, que é gerado dinamicamente através de um `For`. Como recupero esse "`R.id.viewAcima`"?

Comment: Ah, entendi, aquela View também é adicionada dinâmicamente... Acho que complica um pouco, teria que "setar" um `id` diferente para cada uma e usar ali na regra... É necessário usar um `RelativeLayout`, não poderia ser um `LinearLayout` com orientação vertical?

Comment: Poderia ser um `LinearLayout` sim. Ele  ja resolve o problema?

Comment: Problema resolvido. rs